# How can I compare two class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compare

I'm writing my own deep compare and I'm having trouble in comparing two variables that are class components meaning `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)`
To better understand why I'm trying to do lets say I have

```
class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now if

```
const a = <MyComponent/>
const b = <MyComponent/>
```

How to know `a === b` ?
What I mean by `a === b` is that if both a and b are from the same reference, for example if you want to detect props change and one of the props is a component, how can I know its the same one ?
Please note that I want to do this manually so I prefer to not use any comparison library

Comment: Why do you need to compare two components? What about comparing constructor names? `a.constructor.name == b.constructor.name`?

Comment: Please, first define what do you mean by equality between two components.

Comment: @tomashauser you are correct, I fixed the question to reflect this.

Comment: @evolutionxbox What if someone is passing a button as props but he changes the button completely but its still a button ?, will the constructor name be enough ?

Comment: If it's the same component, yes. If they pass in something else, then no. But then nothing else will work either.

Comment: @evolutionxbox constructor.name works but how can i also check the key ?, i want to make sure its the same component with the same key, i don't care if the props of the components or their states or ... are different.

Comment: You can't (I don't think). AFAIK React does not expose the key property.

Comment: @evolutionxbox What do you think happens if someone passes a component as a props to a secondary component, now you change key in the first component, but the secondary component doesn't update its state which is also holding the component passed through props ?

Comment: For now I decided to just use `constructor.name` because it seems `Key` is not exposed in react and my goal was simply to compare these two variables to the best of my ability.